# custom post type with role Vendor

Tags: php, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to create add-ones of WC-Vendors where I have to create custom post type for Vendor user Only.

Here is code snippet I used

```
 register_post_type( 'acme_product',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Products' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
```

**above code works well with admin user.**

Answer (score 1):

First you have to passed two additional arguments into the register_post_type() function.

1. capability_type
2. map_meta_cap

Then, You can add capability using [add_cap();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap) function.

```
register_post_type( 'acme_product',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Products' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'capability_type'  => array('acme_product','acme_products'),
      'map_meta_cap'        => true,
    )
  );

    add_action('admin_init','vendor_role_caps');

    function vendor_role_caps() {

      $role = get_role('vendor_user');
      $role->add_cap( 'read' );
      $role->add_cap( 'read_acme_product');
      $role->add_cap( 'read_private_acme_products' );
      $role->add_cap( 'edit_acme_product' );
      $role->add_cap( 'edit_acme_products' );
      $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_acme_products' );
      $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_acme_products' );
      $role->add_cap( 'publish_acme_products' );
      $role->add_cap( 'delete_others_acme_products' );
      $role->add_cap( 'delete_private_acme_products' );
      $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_acme_products' );

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the **capability** and/or **map_meta_cap** to the argument array of the `register_post_type()`

The codex says : additional capabilities are only used in map_meta_cap(). Thus, they are only assigned by default if the post type is registered with the 'map_meta_cap' argument set to true (default is false).

here is the add_role for the vendor

```
add_role( 'vendor', __('Vendor', 'wcvendors') , array(
         'assign_product_terms'     => true,
         'edit_products'            => true,
         'edit_product'             => true,
         'edit_published_products'  => false,
         'manage_product'           => true,
         'publish_products'         => false,
         'read'                     => true,
         'upload_files'             => true,
         'view_woocommerce_reports' => true,
         ) 
);
```

You will get all details on the codex page [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Comment: we can't add role here. role is already added by Plugin **wc_vendors**.

Comment: You don't need to add rôle, it's just the capatibility you need to match to make it work for vendor